# Unable to add migration in EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.2, command not identified

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

(I use VS 2019 on windows 7 x64)

I follow this tutorial on EntityFramework Core https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-console-application.aspx

According to the tutorial I downloaded EntityFrameworkCore SQLServer 5.0.2., created database context as well as `Student` and `Course` names. Next, it tells me to enter the following command into NuGet console package manager:

```
PM> add-migration CreateSchoolDB
```

Which gives me an error: "The name 'add-migration' isn't recognized as the name of commandlet, function, script file or executable program. Check the validity of name spelling and validity and existence of the path, and try again"

[image]

The tutorial also offers alternative command for dotnet CLI, but VS crashes when I try to open it.
I have no idea where to look to find the root of the problem.

Comment: are you sure that all needed **NuGet packages** are installed? EF/Core etc... 
It seems that you forgot/skipped **Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** part. You should type it into PM and after it will be installed you can migrate your models.

Comment: I just installed the EntityFramework Core itself (even though the tutorial only explicitly told me to install EFC SQLServer, so I assumed I was enough) and restarted Visual Studio. Still the same error. My currently installed packages for the project: https://i.imgur.com/2naitMy.png

Comment: Firstly, you need to install not only **EntityFrameworkCore** itself but **EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer** and also **EntityFrameworkCore**.Tools. So as far there should be 3 packages:
1. EntityFrameworkCore
2. EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
3. EntityFrameworkCore.Tools. 

**NOTE** -- All of them must be the same version e.g 3.1 or whatever common version they have.

I recommend you to take a look at docs also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/install

Comment: @Miraziz Installed EFC Tools, it gives me "script halted" message with no further explanation.